# Compare timestamp date in Postgresql in java

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I am using PostgreSQL database & JPA. Here is my user table

```
   CREATE TABLE users
        (
          id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('userseq'::regclass),
          firstname character varying(64) ,
          middlename character varying(64),
          lastname character varying(64),
          birthdate timestamp with time zone,
         )

    Query query = em
                    .createQuery(
    "SELECT users FROM Users users WHERE user.birthdate =:a")
                            .setParameter("a",18)
                            .setParameter("b",25);
            query.getResultList();
```

I want get all user whose age in between 18-25. Please complete my above JPA query

Comment: you don't need to convert existing `timestamp` of DB. revised the answer, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Between` operator, fix to `user.birthdate` to `users.birthdate` at first.

```
    Calendar cal_1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal_1.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18);
    Date a = cal_1.getTime();
    Calendar cal_2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal_2.add(Calendar.YEAR, -25);
    Date b = cal_2.getTime();

    query.setParameter("a", a);
    query.setParameter("b", b);

    SELECT users FROM Users users WHERE users.eventsDate BETWEEN :a AND :b
```

Example : `x BETWEEN :min AND :max`. Reference [here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/comparison#NOT_BETWEEN_)

Answer (score 2):

JPQL is lacking in date operators. In SQL you'd write something like:

```
SELECT age(TIMESTAMPTZ '1999-01-01') BETWEEN INTERVAL '18' YEAR AND INTERVAL '25' YEAR;
```

but you can't do that in JPQL as far as I can tell. [`BETWEEN` is supported in JPQL](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_between), so I'd convert the date parameters `a` and `b` to `java.util.Date` using `java.util.Calendar`, then use:

```
SELECT users FROM Users users WHERE user.birthdate BETWEEN :a AND :b
```